# Remove weird black outline on Texture when in viewport shading

Tags: texturing

When using the "Texture" option for Color in viewport shading, and your material has the texture interpolation set to "Linear" I get these black outlines around the edges where it's turning transparent. I'm using a 32x64 pixel texture. I'm trying to imitate the Trilinear/Bilinear Filter Mode, that you get in unity to achieve a non pixellated look.

[image: View of Texture and material]
[image: Close up of black outline]
[image: Settings for viewport shading]

Comment: I've seen this before, and I don't remember how to fix it. The short version is that the alpha channel is getting blurred from scaling just like the color channels, but the image will only be either fully transparent or not transparent at all with how the material is set up, so the fuzzy half-transparent areas render as opaque instead.

Comment: Could it be that the _Alpha_ setting in the _Image Texture_ node is _Premultiplied_? At least that's how I get those black borders in semi-transparent areas when using the _Texture_ in _Solid_ mode. If this is the case, try changing it to _Straight_. But the problem here is, the _Solid_ mode cannot show semi-transparency and it can also depend on what colors the image has stored in the transparent areas when you would remove the alpha channel.